# Why does Pi 3 have better WebGL than Pi 4?

Tags: pi-3, performance, pi-4

Based on https://webglsamples.org/fishtank/fishtank.html
Pi 3B, Raspbian Buster, GL driver on, Chromium reports 18 FPS.
Pi 4B4, Raspbian Buster, GL driver on, Chromium reports 12 FPS.

Any idea why this would be? I thought the 4's GPU was considerably faster...

Comment: Are they both running at the same resolution? If not that may be the reason since Pi4 may have higher display defaults and the Pi3 most likely has lower display defaults.

Comment: Is Buster fully updated and are you using the FKMS driver on the Pi4?